# Is there any way to customize legend histogram x-axis or y-axis using tm_layout in R

Tags: r, histogram, tmap

I know that it is possible to customize some features of "legend.hist" from tm_layout such as "legend.hist.height", "legend.hist.size", "legend.hist.width" and so. However, is there some way to customize the x-axis or y-axis like for instance scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(70, 80, by = 2)) from ggplot or even xlim() ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: To give some context I am talking about the function "tm_layout" from the tmap package in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible (yet).

tmap is currently in a big renovation (to v4): we will still have to decide how to proceed with histograms and other legend charts.